# passing a keydown to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, keydown

I want to pass a keydown event to another element. Along the way I found that :

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    $('textarea').keydown()[0].focus();
});
```

works and that:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('textarea').keydown()[0].focus(); }, 0);
});​
```

doesn't work. At least in Chrome.

Anyway I want to do this with the second method as I want it to first be able to do a `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+x` on an input that has text selected and then jump to the textarea.

### [Here's a DEMO to see what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/N7VBM/)

Why doesn't the second way work? Also is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: The first one won't work. you wrote `inout` instead of `input` ...

Comment: @gdoron: fixed and that still didn't address the problem. The demo had it spelled right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works as expected. First of all, half of your code is irrelevant. :p

```
$('inout').keydown(function(e) {
  $('textarea').keydown()[0].focus();
});
```

is equivalent to

```
$('inout').keydown(function(e) {
  $('textarea').keydown(); // doesn't do anything sensible
  $('textarea')[0].focus();
});
```

and it transfers the focus to the `textarea` before the keyhandler resolves. The key ends up in the `textarea`. and the `input` doesn't even see it. (assume the code says `input` and not `inout`).

The second example:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() { $('textarea').keydown()[0].focus(); }, 0);
});​
```

is equivalent to:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('textarea').keydown(); // doesn't do anything sensible
    $('textarea')[0].focus();
  }, 0);
});​
```

so, because of the timeout, first the `keydown` event completes, the key is accepted as input to the `input`, and then the delayed function gets invoked and changes focus. Nothing further happens.

I don't know how to "repeat" or "rethrow" a keyboard event, in case you want to get the same keypress in both `input` and `textarea` (if that's what you wanted; I am not 100% sure what you wanted).

**EDIT**: Okay: if it's just Ctrl/Shift/another modifier key, return true so the default handler picks it up. If it's Ctrl-C (i.e. `C` key with `ctrlKey` set (`metaKey` on Mac), do the timeout thing (so the `input` catches it before the `focus`); if not, move focus immediately (so the `textarea` catches it). Not trivial, and I can't think of a better method at the moment.

Comment: I want it to mainly go to the textarea, but if there's text selected in the input and the user presses ctrl+c I want it to copy what's in the input.

Comment: @gdoron: 1. I did put in a disclaimer addressing it, you might have missed it; 2. `setTimeout(..., 0)` schedules a function immediately after the current code exits (as opposed to immediately-right-now); and 3. is not a mistake, as it makes pretty much zero difference in execution (although it *is* unnecessary, and a teeny bit slower).

Answer (score 0):

Pass enough time for the `setTimeout` delay

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('textarea').keydown()[0].focus(); }, 700); // 0.7 seconds
});
```

the `keydown` event on the `textarea` has no sense, and can be removed;

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() { $('textarea').focus(); }, 700); // 0.7 seconds
});
```